# Find Date difference in mysql between two given dates dynamically from a table and count office leave taken by a user

Tags: mysql, sql, date

[image: Here is the input table]

I am trying to finding out No. of sick leaves,personal leaves etc taken by a user.    So I take out Difference of Leave_from & Leave_to column is taken and 1 day is added to the difference result.i.e same day-same day = 0 + 1 day.I take out sum of the leaves days for SICK, for personal etc.

```
SELECT 
U.ID,   
U.FIRSTNAME,
U.LASTNAME,

L.TITLE,

ULR.LEAVE_TYPE_ID,
ULR.LEAVE_FROM,
ULR.LEAVE_TO,
DATEDIFF(LEAVE_FROM,LEAVE_TO ) AS DiffDate, -- finding date diff dynamically
SUM(DATE_ADD(DiffDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS TOTAL LEAVES -- datediff result is added by 1 day and sum of leave day is taken out 

ULR.LEAVE_DESCRIPTION, 

LST.LEAVE_STATUS



FROM USERS U

LEFT JOIN LEAVE_TYPE L
ON U.ID = L.ID

LEFT JOIN USERS_LEAVE_REQUEST ULR
ON U.ID = ULR.USER_ID

LEFT JOIN LEAVE_STATUS_TABLE LST

ON ULR.USER_ID = LST.USER_ID
```

Comment: MySQL != MS SQL Server

Comment: 1) Please format your code 2)Provide sample data with text form (http://sqlfiddle.com) and desired result 3) Does your code even run?

Comment: i want the output in mysql , u understood the question rite...how to do it

Comment: `DECLARE DATE @LEAVEROM` and `DATEDIFF(day,...)` which dialect it is? This code looks like mix of T-SQL and MySQL. And screen is probably from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: i want to dynamically pass the leave_from & leave_to dates dynamically from a table and find the difference..

Comment: Please provide working data and show your trial. I guess this code won't even run. Am I right?

Comment: the code runs  if i remove the dynamic part i.e (declare & select & date_diff and sum)..now have a look at the code

Answer (score 0):

```
    - Total Employee Leave Detail Report --

SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.firstname,
T1.lastname,
T2.leave_type_id,
T0.title,
T2.leave_from,
T2.leave_to,
DATEDIFF( T2.leave_to, T2.leave_from ) AS Date_Difference,
SUM(DATEDIFF(T2.leave_to,T2.leave_from)+1) AS Total_LeaveDays 

FROM users_leave_request T2        

INNER JOIN users T1 
ON T2.user_id = T1.id
INNER JOIN leave_type T0 
ON T2.leave_type_id = T0.id

GROUP BY
T1.id,
T1.firstname,
T1.lastname,
T2.leave_type_id,
T0.title,
T2.leave_from,
T2.leave_to,
Date_Difference
```